# 18.04.6 LTS DNS problems after upgrading from 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, 18.04, dns, netplan

I've upgraded my headless Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ESM (Extended Security Maintenance) server to 18.04 LTS. Everything went great except the DNS settings are wrong. "netplan" is completely new to me and I don't know how to solve this.
I can ping IP-addresses, but not domains. After some research I found out that I should use netplan and at least one *.yaml file should have been generated and be located in: /etc/netplan. The directory is there, but it's completely empty. I found a "template" in another thread which i edited to to fit my system. It looks like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.11/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4,192.168.0.1]
```

I saved int as "01-netcfg.yaml" in /etc/netplan and ran this commands:

```
sudo netplan generate
```

and:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

I then rebooted, but it had no effect.

The /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
address 192.168.10.14
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.1
dns-nameservers 109.247.114.4 92.220.228.70 192.168.10.1
dns-search lyse.net
```

This is some old IP-addresses and domain from an ISP I used for more than two years ago. I have no idea how and why this old settings is there now because this server have been connected to another ISP and worked fine since 2019.

I've currently run out of ideas on how to fix this. Is there an expert on netplan out there who can help me solve this and maybe know if there is an easy way to reset the network settings with netplan?

The settings I want to use with this settings is this (the same as I've added to the yaml file above):

- No DHCP
- Static IP: 192.168.0.11
- DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
- Gateway: 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading an existing system does not remove or disable ifupdown, which is what processes /etc/network/interfaces.  You also do not have to configure netplan when upgrading.

In your case, you may be experiencing problems because the ifupdown configuration is still active but the DNS servers in question are not responding to your machine's requests.

You should disable the configuration in /etc/network/interfaces (perhaps by moving the file aside, in case you need to restore it later), then reboot to fully remove ifupdown from the equation.  Once you have done this, check the contents of /etc/resolv.conf.  If this file points to `nameserver 127.0.0.53`, then you will want to also check the output of `systemd-resolve --status` to confirm whether the DNS servers listed are the ones you intend to configure.